How to allow IP Based access to StorageAccount in Azure VNet?
We have a scenario where our Storage account inside VNet to restricted to specific public IP range Access. How to allow access to this Storage account inside VNet? Should we create App Service? How to allow access via VNet?

You can select Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses  option in Storage Firewall to allow specific IPs and VNets access to the Storage account, as shown here. Alternatively, you can create an NSG and add a rule like this to restrict IP addresses from accessing the VNet.

@VenkatV I tried by configuring NSG with Inbound rule as Source - Any and destination - VNet. I couldn't access container in storage account. Do we need to specify any public IP or any other configuration to be done?

You can use Storage Firewall option to allow the specific IP traffic to Storage account.as shown here. If you are accessing the storage account from outside the VNET, like Public IP, you need to  add those Public IP's in Firewall section.

In order to do this, please select your storage account and Networking settings

After this choose - Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses

And finally, add your vnet by clicking on "Add existing virtual network"


Plus you can set up Firewall settings there as well

Hope that will help you

do we need to add IP Address under Firewall even after specifying the VNet? Also, how to combine it with NSG?

If this is external IP then yes, I belive you still need to specify those in the firewall.

Turning on firewall rules for your storage account blocks incoming requests for data by default, unless the requests originate from a service that operates within an Azure virtual network or from allowed public IP addresses. Requests that are blocked include those from other Azure services, from the Azure portal, and from logging and metrics services.

How would one translate this to a bicep file using the Azure Verified modules?
https://github.com/Azure/bicep-registry-modules/blob/main/avm/res/storage/storage-account/main.bicep#L399

As Venkat correctly pointed out, in order to allow IP-based access to a Storage Account inside a VNet in Azure, you can configure network rules to grant access to traffic from specific virtual networks and public IP address ranges. You can also add exceptions to allow access from trusted services required for operations such as backing up data and logging and metrics.
Follow below steps-
If you are creating a new storage account, then select enable network access from selected virtual network and IP

If storage account already created, modify the same under the networking tab like this to allow the specific IP to the storage account.

For example before enabling this option under networking -> Firewall I was not able to access the container

after adding the public IP under firewall settings, I can access the storage container from my local machine.

References:

Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks
Grant access from an internet IP range

